# Alternative to create a menu in visual studio 2013 express

Tags: express, visual-studio-2013, menu

I tried following this article ([https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b6tafew(v=vs.120).aspx)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b6tafew(v=vs.120).aspx) but then realized when reading the note that this option is not available in visual studio express versions.  Doe anybody have advice for me on an alternative to creating a menu in express version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching I found menustrip option